# Publish new facebook post with tagged product

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm using Facebook's Graph API to publish a new post on my page, essentially I currently have the following HTTP request:

> HOST: graph.facebook.com
> POST /v2.10/{page-id}/feed?access_token={token}
>
> message=example
> link=www.example.com

Now I would like to add the product's tag, but the [/page/feed API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.10/page/feed) has no mentioning of this.
The following image shows what action I would like to achieve:

[image: Tag product from Facebook post]

Is this possible to do?