# How to post a photo to a page with a tagged Product via Graph API v12.0?

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

We have a Facebook Shop and a Business Page, and are using Facebook Graph API to create Photo posts on the Business Page using the Javascript SDK running in a browser.  How do you include the tagged Product in the Create Photo request?

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/photo/ mentions a `tags` field you can pass which is described as "Tags on this photo", however it has a `tag_uid` "The user_id of the tagged person".  Is this `tags` field how you are supposed to tag a product?

A similar question from 2017 was not answered and is so old I thought I'd post a new one: [Publish new facebook post with tagged product](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45235105/publish-new-facebook-post-with-tagged-product)

### What we've tried so far

To get a list of our products, we can use `GET ${businessId}/owned_product_catalogs` to retrieve a list of catalogs, and then `GET ${productCatId/products` with a `filter: '{"custom_label_0":{"eq":"something_to_match"}}'` to get a specific product in the catalog.  So now we have the ID of a product we want to tag e.g. "4378279312278116". (we happen to use `custom_label_x` fields meaningfully, of course the `filter` could have been something else but this works for us)

To create the photo post, we can `POST /${account.id}/photos` with a payload like:

```
{ caption: 'Test caption',
  url: image_url,
  access_token: account.access_token,
  tags: [
    {
      tag_uid: "4378279312278116",
      tag_text: 'Test tag',
      x: 10, y: 10
    }
  ]
}
```

This request completes OK and does post the photo, but nothing is tagged on it when we view it on our page.

Trying to read the photo with `GET ${photo_id}` only returns basic infomation fields `created_time`, `id`, `name`.  I can't see how to read further fields on the photo object to check if the tags data was associated with it correctly.

Any advice please?

Comment: _"Trying to read the photo with GET ${photo_id} only returns basic infomation fields created_time, id, name. I can't see how to read further fields"_ - you need to explicitly _ask_ for additional fields, otherwise most edges will only return you a small subset of default fields. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/overview#fields

Comment: _"How do you include the tagged Product in the Create Photo request?"_ - I don't think that is possible with normal photo posts. What you are talking about, is probably located somewhere in the realm of the Marketing API, because it does sound like _ads_, not normal photos.

Comment: Thanks @CBroe .. Good call, I thought I'd read that `fields` was deprecated but https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/overview#fields says it's valid.  I tried `GET 4680938491955793?fields=tags` (the id of a photo with a manually tagged product) but got back `(#100) Tried accessing nonexisting field (tags) on node type (Photo)`.

Comment: @CBroe I have spent some time reading the Marketing API docs at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-apis/ but it's all about Ads, ad campaigns, and the like.  The closest seems to be https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/reference/product-set/ which is about creating a set of Products which you then relate to an Ad, nothing to do with tags on a Post or Photo object.  If it's in there I've love to see what I'm missing :)

Comment: Correction: the id I gave before was for a Photo, but it seems it belongs to a PagePost and it may be that which holds the tag.  So, I called `GET ${accountId}/posts` and retrieved the post id in which I'd tagged the picture, called `GET 105823586133996_4700561173326858?fields=tags` but got a similar `"(#100) Tried accessing nonexisting field (tags) on node type (PagePost)"` (this time mentioning `PagePost` instead of `Photo` in my previous comment.  So, still no dice.

Comment: Small update: A colleague has started using a product called Agorapulse to schedule posting to Facebook, so he works 1 day a week and lines up several posts to be created at regular intervals through the rest of the week.  This product seems to provide no way of tagging Products, although their marketing-speak documentation says one can tag products as a general concept.  Perhaps this is also because the Graph API simply doesn't provide a way of doing it.

Comment: I asked facebook support, and is not implement to tag products just people, only on instagram business page when post you can tag that photo with `product_tags`

Comment: Thanks @BoBiTza - tagging products in an IG post might be nice for us to do, I'll try to find time to look into it, though we have much stronger engagement on our FB posts than IG ones (with pretty much the same image and text content) so it's lower priority.